# Cartesian product of union

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I would like to know if the way I solve this exercise is correct, and if there is a shorter way to make the demonstration. Here is the exercise :

Given :

- $E$ and $F$ two sets,
- $I$ an indexed family,
- $(A_i)_{i \in I}$ an indexed family of $E$,
- $(B_i)_{i \in I}$ an indexed family of $F$,

Show that : $\bigcup_{i \in I} (A_i \times B) = \left( \bigcup_{i \in I} A_i \right) \times B$

Then I wrote :

1. If $x = (a,b) \in \bigcup_{i \in I} (A_i \times B)$, then $\exists i \in I, (a \in A_i \wedge b \in B)$, then $(\exists i \in I, a \in A_i) \wedge (\exists i \in I, b \in B)$, then $a \in \left( \bigcup_{i \in I} A_i \right) \wedge b \in B$, so $x \in \left( \bigcup_{i \in I} A_i \right) \times B$
2. If $x = (a,b) \in \left( \bigcup_{i \in I} A_i \right) \times B$, then $(\exists i \in I, a \in A_i) \wedge (b \in B)$, then $(\exists i \in I, a \in A_i) \wedge (\forall i \in I, b \in B)$, then $\exists i \in I, (a \in A_i \wedge b \in B)$, so $x \in \bigcup_{i \in I} (A_i \times B)$

As a conclusion : $\bigcup_{i \in I} (A_i \times B) = \left( \bigcup_{i \in I} A_i \right) \times B$

Can anyone confirm everything is correct ? Is there a way to show it using equivalence ?

Thanks !

Comment: This is a bit more complicated than it needs to be (although I am guessing this is in the context of first learning how to write proofs like this, so a bit more detail than necessary can be useful), but it's correct. As a note, your proof would be much easier to read when written with more words rather than symbols

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is good.

Another way to see it:

$\bigcup_{i \in I} (A_i \times B)$ = { m | ∃i∈I[(m∈($A_i$$\times$B)] }

= { (a,b) | ∃i∈I(a∈$A_i$) and b∈B}

= { (a,b) | a∈$\bigcup_{i \in I}(A_i)$ and b∈B }

= $\bigcup_{i \in I}(A_i)$ $\times$ B